# Dagger hilt: Difference between annotating a class @Singleton and a provides function @Singleton

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger, dagger-hilt

My question is pretty simple and straightforward: What is the difference between the two annotations / examples:

### Example one

```
@Singleton
class MySingletonClass() {}

@Module
@InstallIn(FragmentComponent::class)
abstract class MyFragmentModule {
   @Provides
   fun provideMySingletonClass() = MySingletonClass()
}
```

### Eaxmple two

```
class MySingletonClass() {}

@Module
@InstallIn(FragmentComponent::class)
abstract class MyFragmentModule {

   @Singleton
   @Provides
   fun provideMySingletonClass() = MySingletonClass()
}
```

The only difference I know is, that the second example gives me the following error:

```
error: [Dagger/IncompatiblyScopedBindings] FragmentC scoped with @dagger.hilt.android.scopes.FragmentScoped may not reference bindings with different scopes:
```

Does that mean, that the `@Singleton` annotation in example one is simply ignored?

Comment: Your top level Component is most likely annotated with `@Singleton` meaning `MySingletonClass` can be used with that component.  You cannot have mixed scopes in a component/subcomponent, dependencies either have the same scope as the component/subcomponent or are unscoped.  In this case everywhere you use `MySingletonClass` it will be the same instance in the dependency graph but don't get confused as this class is not a true "singleton", it just means its a shared instance in the context of this dependency graph. `@Singleton` is simply a name of a scope that comes with the library.

Comment: @MarkKeen So does that mean that in my example one, `@Singleton` is simply ignored and is not a "true" singleton

Comment: I was explaining the error, which is completely different to your question - your rationale for the question doen't really fit the error.  As pointed out in below answer you missed `@Inject` on the `MySingletonClass` class so its not visible to Dagger. However if you add the `@Inject` annotation you will get the same error until you remove `@Singleton @Provides fun provideMySingletonClass() = MySingletonClass()` from your fragment module.  The semantics of which are explained in my above comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Example One, **your `@Singleton` annotation is ignored, but only because you are calling the constructor yourself in your `@Provides` method**. Because Dagger doesn't interact with your `MySingletonClass` constructor, it cannot read or use the annotation.

If your `@Singleton class MySingletonClass` had an `@Inject constructor`—even an empty one—then Dagger would be able to interact with it directly *as long as* you also delete the `@Provides fun` that would override the constructor detection. Once you've done that, the behavior of `@Singleton` would be the same in either syntax.

---

**Regarding the error message** "error: [Dagger/IncompatiblyScopedBindings] XXX scoped with @YYY may not reference bindings with different scopes": @Andrew The real problem here is that in Example Two you're trying to declare a @Singleton binding in a Module that you install in your FragmentComponent. @Singleton bindings can only happen in a @Singleton component, [which in Hilt is SingletonComponent](https://dagger.dev/hilt/migration-guide.html#1-migrate-the-application). I don't remember for sure, but I think your Example One (with the edits I described) would work with singleton behavior and without an error, because Dagger would automatically select the appropriate component in the hierarchy to install your MySingletonClass.

Comment: Why can't I make a fragment-dependency @Singleton? Is @FragmentScoped here the alternative?

Comment: @Andrew The real problem here is that in Example Two you're trying to declare a `@Singleton` binding in a Module that you install in your FragmentComponent. `@Singleton` bindings can only happen in a `@Singleton` component, [which in Hilt is `SingletonComponent`](https://dagger.dev/hilt/migration-guide.html#1-migrate-the-application). I don't remember for sure, but I think your Example One (with the edits I described) would work with singleton behavior and without an error, because Dagger would automatically select the appropriate component in the hierarchy to install your `MySingletonClass`.

Comment: @Andrew Use a `@Singleton` binding in `SingletonComponent` if you want one instance in the entire app, or a `FragmentScoped` binding in `FragmentComponent` if you want one instance per fragment.  Either way, the binding is accessible in `FragmentComponent`.